# how is Entityframework 4 automaticlaly mapping the database schema without any dbmodelbuilder in code first approach

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am new to entity framework and mvc, I tried creating a MVC 4 application and do a CRUD operation using entity framework , I created a model "User" and  with properties id, firstname , lastname and ran the application , entity framework gave me a table in my database automatically, I wonder how is the background mapping happening here, I see the databaseSetInitializer method is also commented by default. , so how is it creating the database and mapping if I later add or remove records ? On the other end I see in some application they have used mapping by overriding the OnModelCreating event and adding the configuration maps their for each table and the respective columns, so somene please clarify me why is that really used and how did that magically work for me in my trail without these mapping code. ? The code below.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                var schemaName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EFSchemaName"];
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(schemaName))
                {
                    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserMap(schemaName));
                    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new BookMap(schemaName));
                    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CollegeMap(schemaName));
                    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AreaMap(schemaName));
                    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new StateMap(schemaName));
                    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new LanguageMap(senter code herechemaName));
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new ConfigurationErrorsException("'EFSchema' setting not found.");
                }
            }
```

Comment: Code First has a lot of built in Conventions that it will use if you do not provide your own configuration. For example, an entity named User will map to dbo.Users. If that class has an Id property or a UserId property it will treat that as the primary key. Take a look at the MSDN documentation to see a full list of conventions.

Comment: In addtion to @Dismissile: EF (code first) uses reflection of the properties and arguments to determine the database schema. If you remove or add properties EF will detect it but it will not change the schema again. In that case you should use the Migration package.

Comment: @Dismissile and marthijn: Thanks for the comments ,I guessed what you said as it worked for me by default without any extra code but my doubt is in one of mvc application I saw theres the above code I attached doing some explicit mappings using modelbuilder , what for is it required if EF by default mapping the schema ? what's the extra its doing ?